# what is ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.ZipEntry.Flag?

Tags: icsharpcode

Will any one please give an example, I googled but not found any suitable result.

I want to give flag so that it compress the file with its original name in case of file name

with special characters.for example currently I am using

```
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.FullName.Substring(directory.FullName.Length + 1));
                    entry.Flags |= 2048; // enable UTF8 file names
```

what should be the flag to support special charaters file name??

Thanx

Answer (score 3):

Source code for this component is available here:

http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/Download.aspx

If you download the source and review the code for ZipEntry, you'll find the following comments for the `Flags` property.

```
///
/// Get/Set general purpose bit flag for entry
///
///
/// General purpose bit flag
///
/// Bit 0: If set, indicates the file is encrypted
/// Bit 1-2 Only used for compression type 6 Imploding, and 8, 9 deflating
/// Imploding:
/// Bit 1 if set indicates an 8K sliding dictionary was used.  If clear a 4k dictionary was used
/// Bit 2 if set indicates 3 Shannon-Fanno trees were used to encode the sliding dictionary, 2 otherwise
///
/// Deflating:
///   Bit 2    Bit 1
///     0        0       Normal compression was used
///     0        1       Maximum compression was used
///     1        0       Fast compression was used
///     1        1       Super fast compression was used
///
/// Bit 3: If set, the fields crc-32, compressed size
/// and uncompressed size are were not able to be written during zip file creation
/// The correct values are held in a data descriptor immediately following the compressed data.
/// Bit 4: Reserved for use by PKZIP for enhanced deflating
/// Bit 5: If set indicates the file contains compressed patch data
/// Bit 6: If set indicates strong encryption was used.
/// Bit 7-10: Unused or reserved
/// Bit 11: If set the name and comments for this entry are in <a href="http://www.unicode.org">unicode</a>.
/// Bit 12-15: Unused or reserved
///
/// <seealso cref="IsUnicodeText"></seealso>
/// <seealso cref="IsCrypted"></seealso>
```

So, ORing 2048 into Flags as you have done looks correct.  Or, you could set the IsUnicodeText property which does the same thing, though makes the code look a little cleaner:

```
entry.IsUnicodeText = true;
```